# Tailwind CSS Group Hover with SVG children only works on the first element and not remaining children

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I've run into this issue with TailwindCSS (version 3.2.4) group-hover where group hovering elements with SVG children only seems to work on the first element, and not the remaining elements.

I've created an example on the TailwindCSS playground here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/LgiQDbYH8K

Hovering over any of the elements should make the caret SVG appear. This seems to happen on the first element, but not the second or third elements.

Replacing the SVG with text makes it work again. I haven't tried any other HTML elements.

Tested on Chrome and Firefox, same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `ids` are the same. It made me lose my mind on a project too. You have to give unique ids and set the same in urls clip-paths

Here is the code :

```
<div>
  <div class="group/result cursor-pointer p-10">
    <div class="invisible absolute group-hover/result:visible">
      <svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <g clip-path="url(#mysvgone)">
          <path d="M5.757 24c-.414 0-1.036-.207-1.243-.622-.622-.622-.415-1.658.207-2.28l10.983-9.118L4.721 2.862c-.622-.622-.829-1.658-.207-2.28.621-.621 1.658-.828 2.28-.207l12.433 10.362c.415.414.622.829.622 1.243 0 .415-.207 1.037-.622 1.244L6.793 23.585A1.582 1.582 0 0 1 5.757 24Z"></path>
        </g>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="mysvgone">
            <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>Test 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-8 border-b border-neutral-300"></div>
  <div class="group/result cursor-pointer p-10">
    <div class="invisible absolute group-hover/result:visible">
      <svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <g clip-path="url(#mysvgtwo)">
          <path d="M5.757 24c-.414 0-1.036-.207-1.243-.622-.622-.622-.415-1.658.207-2.28l10.983-9.118L4.721 2.862c-.622-.622-.829-1.658-.207-2.28.621-.621 1.658-.828 2.28-.207l12.433 10.362c.415.414.622.829.622 1.243 0 .415-.207 1.037-.622 1.244L6.793 23.585A1.582 1.582 0 0 1 5.757 24Z"></path>
        </g>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="mysvgtwo">
            <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-8 border-b border-neutral-300"></div>
  <div class="group/result cursor-pointer p-10">
    <div class="invisible absolute group-hover/result:visible">
      <svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <g clip-path="url(#mysvgthree)">
          <path d="M5.757 24c-.414 0-1.036-.207-1.243-.622-.622-.622-.415-1.658.207-2.28l10.983-9.118L4.721 2.862c-.622-.622-.829-1.658-.207-2.28.621-.621 1.658-.828 2.28-.207l12.433 10.362c.415.414.622.829.622 1.243 0 .415-.207 1.037-.622 1.244L6.793 23.585A1.582 1.582 0 0 1 5.757 24Z"></path>
        </g>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="mysvgthree">
            <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>Test 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah geez... Glad to hear it didn't just stump me, and more glad to see a well explained solution. Thanks! I struggled to find any other posts talking about this, I'm surprised no one else has hit it. Or someone has, and this will help them in the future hopefully...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026334/tailwind-css-group-hover-with-svg-children-only-works-on-the-first-element-and-n/#75028825) this issue is related to duplicate ids.

However, you can easily avoid this by defining your icon once in a [`<symbol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) and referencing multiple instances in a [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) element - no renaming of IDs required.

```css
/* ! tailwindcss v3.2.4 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
5. Use the user's configured `sans` font-feature-settings by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  /* 5 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  font-weight: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Make elements with the HTML hidden attribute stay hidden by default */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

::-webkit-backdrop {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

::backdrop {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.mx-8 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.border-b {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.border-neutral-300 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(212 212 212 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.p-10 {
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.group\/result:hover .group-hover\/result\:visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="group/result cursor-pointer p-10">
    <div class="invisible absolute group-hover/result:visible">
      <svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <use href="#caretRight" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>Test 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-8 border-b border-neutral-300"></div>
  <div class="group/result cursor-pointer p-10">
    <div class="invisible absolute group-hover/result:visible">
      <svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <use href="#caretRight" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-8 border-b border-neutral-300"></div>
  <div class="group/result cursor-pointer p-10">
    <div class="invisible absolute group-hover/result:visible">
      <svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <use href="#caretRight" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>Test 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true">
  <symbol id="caretRight" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M5.757 24c-.414 0-1.036-.207-1.243-.622-.622-.622-.415-1.658.207-2.28l10.983-9.118L4.721 2.862c-.622-.622-.829-1.658-.207-2.28.621-.621 1.658-.828 2.28-.207l12.433 10.362c.415.414.622.829.622 1.243 0 .415-.207 1.037-.622 1.244L6.793 23.585A1.582 1.582 0 0 1 5.757 24Z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

You can also use external references like `<use href="icons.svg#icon" />` provided the icon svg is hosted on the same domain.

[Tailwind play example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/G5IjccXRG9)

BTW. your clip path doesn't clip anything - you can savely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My observation is that the issue is "id" related but in my case the "id"'s were not required at all.

Specifically:

1. The "id"s were present in the SVG itself (multiple).
2. The SVGs were registered for use in Angular Material "mat-icons" using `matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon()`.

The solution for me was to remove all "id"'s (I chose to rename as "x-id" attributes as the "id"s originated from a vector tool used to edit the SVG so I did not want to lose them altogether).